# Unexpected behavior of AddConstRef metafunction

Tags: c++

Consider this code snippet.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct AddConstRef {
    using type = const T&;
};

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_same<int&, AddConstRef<int&>::type>::value);
    return 0;
}
```

Why does this code compile? I expect AddConstRef<int&>::type to be equal to `const int&` and the static_assert to fail.

Comment: You tried to make a reference to another reference...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const T&` is a reference to "const T". So `const` is applied first, then `&` is applied to the result.

References themselves can't be `const`, so `int &const` doesn't compile. But if you try to add constness to a reference in a template, it will be silently ignored.

So, given `T = int &`, `const T` is also `int &`. Then you apply `&` to it, which has no effect, since it's already a reference.